# How to make another pc in the same lan forward a packet?

Tags: networking, iptables

I might not be phrasing correctly using the word 'forward'. Basically I am trying to make this happen:

I have two PCs in the same LAN. A has the ip addr of 192.168.1.3 and B has 192.168.1.4. I want A to send packets to a remote public ip address 72.xx.xx.xx, however, instead of having A directly send packets to that public ip, I want A to send packets to B first,(192.168.1.3 -> 192.168.1.4), and B can forward A's packets to that remote public ip, and finally A can also get response back correctly.

I tried adding some NAT rules in iptables but had no luck. Anyone having some suggestions? Thanks:)

Comment: Add a static route on `A` for the destination IP address `72.xx.xx.xx` with next-hop IP address 192.168.1.4, the IP address of `B`.

Comment: If doing what is proposed in previous comment please remember to enable ip_forwarding on B. Additionally take the note that this will not cover the return path, only forward path will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I entirely understand the question, but if you just want the traffic to be routed to an ip via another box on your LAN, as I see mentioned in the comments, all you need to do is add an entry to the route table which makes the gateway for 72.xx.xx.xx as 192.168.1.4.
Try

```
ip route add 72.xx.xx.xx via 192.168.1.4
```

Since ip forwarding is generally disabled by default on linux systems, you'll have to enable it on 192.168.1.4
Just do

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Now, to get the response back into the 192.168.1.3 box, easiest way is to enable masquerading on 192.168.1.4 box.
Just do

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This will of course masquerade all connections from any sources and to any destinations.

Comment: Hey johnzac thanks for you reply! Your answer is great but there is one little misunderstanding. I actually want A to explicitly send packets to B, so that will be, say in the browser's address bar, you type http://192.168.1.4, and then B sees this incoming request, it instead forwards the request to the remote public ip. The key idea here would be A does not talk to the remote network at all, all it does is to talk to B explicitly first.